# How to split zip-file (or rar-file) in many files

Tags: file-management, zip, rar

I have a huge file I need to send over the Internet and I want to use SkyDrive but it has a 50MB limit per file.

How can I zip and split my file in many small (50MB) ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tool like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/) should be able to do it. Many programs can open .7z and .rar files so your recipient shouldn't have much trouble opening it. Of the two, I would suggest 7-Zip over WinRAR.

Here's [a guide to help](http://www.linglom.com/2008/10/12/how-to-split-a-large-file-using-7-zip/).

Comment: thanx, winrar did it! :)

Answer (score 1):

What operating system do you use?  Under *nix or Windows with Cygwin, you can compress the files into a single archive, then use the "split" command to break it into pieces of any preferred size, and "cat" to recombine them.  You can also take a checksum before and after the operation to make sure everything went right.

Answer (score 1):

Use WinRAR's "Split To Volumes, bytes" feature. Right click on the file and then select that feature. There are already some sizes predefined, you should add the size that you want.

Other file archive/compression tools have similar features:

- [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)
- [PeaZip](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/)
- [FreeArc](http://www.freearc.org/)

Answer (score 1):

WinRAR should be suitable - I use it myself and feel it really does a great job.

All you need to do is install the WinRAR software and once installed, right click on your 50MB file and select *Add to Archive*. Choose either RAR or ZIP then you're done!